# How to tell the status of a Linux Daemon

Tags: linux, bash, daemon

We have a Linux Daemon in c and a bash script to start it. The daemon sometimes fail to start because of some configuration file errors but the script reports the daemon was started successfully. A snippet of the script is shown as below, could someone tell me what's wrong with the script?

```
...
case "$1" in
start)
echo -n "Starting Demo Daemon: "
sudo -u demouser env DEMO_HOME=$DEMO_HOME /usr/local/demouser/bin/democtl startup > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
    echo_success
else
    echo_failure
fi
echo
;;
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's really difficult to figure out what's wrong with your script when we have no idea what it is supposed to do.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but you can do your redirect like this: ` > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 6):

I feel there is nothing wrong with the script,it is the reponsibility of daemon to return non zero exit status if failed to start properly and based on those the script will display the message.(which i think it does)

Comment: Both `sudo` and `env` preserve the exit code, so it's probably really the daemon itself which doesn't set the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add following line in your script to get running status of your Linux Daemon

```
status=`ps -aef |grep "\/usr\/local\/demouser\/bin\/democtl" |grep -v grep|wc -l`
if [ "$status" = "1" ]; then
  echo_success
else
  echo_failure
fi
```